# How to hide this message using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on a condition i am assigning a new message to a variable then showing the message using jquery.Now after 2 seconds i want to hide the message and show another new message.The problem is as i am not showing the message into a html div so i am confused how to attain this ?

```
if(newresp == "success")
{
var newmsg="<img src=\"images/myimg.png\"><span style='color:#00CCFF;font-size:25px;margin-top:2px'> validated!</span>";
var newmsg1="redirecting ......";
$("#status").hide().fadeIn('slow').html(newmsg);
// i want to hide this newmsg now and then show the newmsg1

}
```

Comment: why don't you wrap the `image` and `span` in a `div` and give the `div` an `id`, then you can hide the `div` and show the new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `javascript` [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method.

```
if(newresp == "success")
{
var newmsg="<img src='images/myimg.png'><span style='color:#00CCFF;font-size:25px;margin-top:2px'> validated!</span>";
var newmsg1="redirecting ......";

    $( "#status" ).hide().fadeIn( 500 ).html(newmsg).delay( 2000 ).fadeOut( 500 );

    setTimeout(function() {
        $( "#status" ).hide().fadeIn(500 ).html(newmsg1).delay( 2000 ).fadeOut( 500 );
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location='http://google.com';
}, 6000);
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/k9vg305a/6/)

The first `SetTimeout` delay is `3000` (3 seconds), the sum of time the first message is visible (`500`+`2000`+`500`)
The second `SetTimeout` delay is `6000` (3''+3'') and then redirects.

Comment: only getting the second message!

Comment: @query the demo  link  was outdated, please try again.

Comment: Thanks at last got the solution!one more thing i want to redirect after the second message but when i add parent.location.href='http://a.com'; the second message is not showing though i tried with increased delay time!

Comment: @query let me take a look at it, 1m

Comment: @query I've updated my answer. Please note that jsfiddle doesn't allow  `window.location` , but I've tested the code on my computer and it works.

Answer (score 1):

not sure about your entire scenario, but [here's a quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oLncxswo/) to demonstrate the idea.

basically you want to wrap the content in a `div` or something and give it an `id` so you can call it specifically

Answer (score 0):

Create new DOM elements like this:

```
var img = $('<img src=\"images/myimg.png\">');
var span = $('<span style="color:#00CCFF;font-size:25px;margin-top:2px"> validated!</span>');
```

Then `.append()` them both to the div and fade it in. You need to wait for the fade to finish like this:

```
$(selector).fadeIn('slow', function() {
    // will be called when the element finishes fading in
});
```

Then you can say: `$('div.status span').html('Your new message');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery delay function to wait.

So...

```
$("#status").hide().fadeIn('slow').html(newmsg).delay( 20000 ).fadeOut('slow').delay( 20000 ).html(newmsg1).fadeIn('slow');
```

This gives a 2 second delay between both. 2000 is milliseconds = 2 seconds

Edit:
Use the setTimeout function instead...

```
var newmsg="<span style='color:#00CCFF;font-size:25px;margin-top:2px'>Your click is validated!</span>";
var newmsg1="ok";
$("#verify_status").hide().html(newmsg).fadeIn('slow', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#verify_status").hide().html(newmsg1).fadeIn('slow');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: var newmsg="<span style='color:#00CCFF;font-size:25px;margin-top:2px'>Your click is validated!</span>";
var newmsg1="ok";
$("#verify_status").hide().html(newmsg).fadeIn('slow', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#verify_status").hide().html(newmsg1).fadeIn('slow');
    }, 2000);
});